# Get Grid.Column property from sender

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm pretty new around WP/Visual C# and I'm currently making a project that involves a grid (with cols and rows) filled 100+ buttons, I have created a general function for all them, but I do need to know which one was actually pressed, I figured out the "Grid.Column" "Grid.Row" properties in the buttons, and I use them to place in the right spot each button.

Property:

```
<Button Content="" Margin="-12,-12,0,-13" Width="69" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderThickness="2" Background="{x:Null}" Padding="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

But what I can't do is to get this properties from my button code, I have tried this:

```
int rows = ((Button)sender).Grid.rows;
```

Which gives me this error:

```
Error 1: 'System.Windows.Controls.Button' does not contain a definition for 'Grid' and no extension method 'Grid' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Button' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  C:\Users\K\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\buscaminas\bus\MainPage.xaml.cs    71
```

Is there any solution? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called attached dependency property. You need to use the class, that declares them to access.

```
var row = Grid.GetRow((Button)sender);
var col = Grid.GetColumn((Button)sender);
```

Comment: Just one more thing, what should I do in order to set then a property to that specific button?

Comment: If you mean Grid attached properties like Row, Column, RowSpan, ColumnSpan, they all have setter methods. Grid.SetXXX(FrameworkElement, value)

Comment: Not really :S, I want to change for example the "Content" property of the button contained at a specific Grid at row=0, col=0

Comment: In this case you need to use VisualTreeHelper class to discover all children in your grid, then find one with required Row/Column, cast it to button and set button content